# Merge CSV into HDF5 in pandas leads to crash

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have about 700 `CSV` files.  They are each typically a few meg and few thousand rows.  So, the total folder is ~1gig.  I want to merge them into a single `HDF5` file.

I first defined a function `read_file(file)` that reads a single file, and parses it using `pd.read_csv()`.  It then returns a dataframe.

I then use this code to convert:

```
    for file in files:
         print (file + " Num: "+str(file_num)+" of: "+str(len(files)))
         file_num=file_num+1
         in_pd=read_file(file)
         in_pd.to_hdf('AllFlightLogs.h5','flights',mode='a',append=True)
```

And, it works just fine for about 202 files, and then python crashes with: `Abort trap: 6`
I don't know what this error means.  I have also seen it pop up a window showing a stack error.

I have tried using `complib='lzo'` and that doesn't seem to make any difference.  I have tried saving to a different hdf5 file every 100 reads, and that does change the exact number of files before the crash.  But, it still happens.

There doesn't seem to be anything special about that particular file.  Is there anyway to find out anything else about this particular error?  I know that the crash happens when I try to call `in_pd.to_hdf()` (I added print statements before and after).

I am running on a `Mac`, and using `pandas 16.2`.

Comment: What's your version of PyTables? Note that PyTables 3.2 has [this](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/455) known bug which causes the interpreter to crash.

Comment: Yes, 3.2.  That's the newest in macports.  Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to 3.2.1 and that seems to have fixed it.  So, it was not a problem with my code (which was driving me crazy), but was a pytables problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adam's answer solved my problem on my imac.
But as of 1sep15, while pytables is available for linux and osx, it is still not for Windows - I use the Anaconda distribution (very good in every other respect). Does anybody know why ? Is there a specific reason for that ?

Comment: Just a guess, but it looks like that distribution was last updated on July 2 and I think this fix is more recent.